# Facebook PHP SDK - Share a link via app

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm currently using custom actions to post user updates from my app - the disadvantage being there's no guarantee the action will appear on user's wall.

Instead I would like to "share" the link, ie.:
[image: Share]

How can I achieve this with the PHP SDK? I tried to use

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                array(
                    'link' => 'www.example.com',
                    'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                ));
```

But that posts directly, instead of appearing as "share".

Comment: I'd recommend the JS SDK for this simple task: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: I need to do this programatically, with access token only, without user interaction.

Comment: What do you mean by `posts directly, instead of appearing as "share".`

Comment: When I use the method above, it appears on facebook as regular user's post, instead of "share link via app" type of post.